Is there a way to approximate a set of wavelengths for a given RGB color?
I am trying to write a simple CLI tool in python for finding a set of wavelengths, that when converted to RGB and then combined, are close to the input RGB color.
I cannot find a good method to do this, I have found plenty of methods to do the inverse though.
I would preferably have code that generates the smallest amount of wavelengths needed to represent the color, like for blue you only need 1, for some others maybe 2.

There are extremely few colors that can be obtained with a single wavelength.  Not many that can be had with 2 either.  For the majority you're going to need 3, and you might as well use RGB at that point.

I take back some of what I said earlier, you should be able to generate any point within the CIE diagram by combining different intensities of two points from the perimeter.  Getting those two points will be hard and converting them to wavelengths will be harder.

It sounds like dominant wavelength might be useful for you?
Almost no RGB values can represent the colour of pure wavelengths (definitely not sRGB), no matter how they are combined, but you can calculate their dominant wavelength and excitation purity.
There is a python colour library that can calculate these, as well as my own .NET Unicolour library. I've also written up some details about wavelength and purity here.
With regards to "a set of wavelengths", that's tricky. Every colour can be generated by infinite different spectral power distributions (metamerism). Dominant wavelength could be a useful starting point (i.e. a spectral power distribution of a single wavelength).
There is a paper (Physically Meaningful Rendering using Tristimulus Colours) that attempts to convert sRGB to spectra, but it aims to generate a distribution that "resembles natural spectra as much as possible", which sounds at odds with what you're trying to do. However it looks like the python colour library also implements that if it's useful.
